# Number of zeroes of solution to $y''(x)+e^{x^2}y(x)=0$ in $[0,3π]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to investigate the number of zeroes of $y''(x)+e^{x^2}y(x)=0$ in $[0,3π]$.

Solving this ODE would not be an easy task as one has to use the power series solution and then investigating the zeroes of the solution will require more analysis. I thought it to compare this ODE with the standard $y''(x)+y(x)=0$ whose solution has three or four zeroes in the interval $[0,3π]$.

Since the coefficient of $y(x)$ is $e^{x^2}\ge 1$ for $x\in [0,3π]$ so the solution of given ODE must have atleast three zeroes in $[0,3π]$. However, what  I thought was in the lights of Sturm-Comparison theorem so I am not sure.

Am I correct to interpret this?

Comment: @projectilemotion..by Kneser's theorem it surely has oscillating solution but I want to know the number of zeroes.

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any function $\eta: [0,3\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, consider functions of the form
$$y_\eta(x) = \Im \left[ \exp\left( -\eta(x) + i\int_0^x e^{2\eta(t)} dt + K\right)\right]$$
where $K$ is an arbitrary constant. It is easy to check $y_\eta(x)$ satisfies an ODE

$$y_\eta''(x) + p_\eta(x)y_\eta(x) = 0
\quad\text{ where }\quad p_\eta(x) = e^{4\eta(x)} + \eta''(x) - \eta'(x)^2\tag{*1}
$$

When $\eta(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}$, this reduces to
$$y_\eta''(x) + \left(e^{x^2} + \frac{2-x^2}{4}\right)y_\eta(x) = 0\tag{*2}$$

Compare this to the ODE at hand

$$y''(x) + p(x)y(x) = 0 \quad\text{ where }\quad p(x) = e^{x^2}\tag{*3}$$

They look "approximately" the same. More precisely, the relative difference between the coefficients of the two ODE, $\frac{p_\eta(x) - p(x)}{p(x)} = \frac{2-x^2}{4}e^{-x^2}$, become tiny as $x$ increases. For example, at $x = 2$, this relative difference already falls below $1\%$. This suggests we can use solutions of $(*2)$ to bound the number of zeros for solutions of $(*3)$.

Notice $p(x) \ge p_\eta(x)$ for $x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi]$. By [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem), we have

$$\#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\} \ge \#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y_\eta(x) = 0\big\} - 1$$

In general, if $x_1$ is a zero for $y_\eta(x)$ and $x_2 > x_1$ satisfies
$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^{2\eta(t)} dt = \pi$, then $x_2$ is also a zero.
When we set $K$ to $-i\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}e^{t^2/2}dt$, $\sqrt{2}$ becomes a zero of $y_\eta(x)$. For this particular choice of $K$,

$$\begin{align}
 & \#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y_\eta(x) = 0\big\}
= \left\lfloor \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{3\pi} e^{t^2/2} dt\right\rfloor + 1\\
\implies &
\#\big\{ x \in [0,3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\}
\ge \#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\}
\ge \left\lfloor \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{3\pi} e^{t^2/2} dt\right\rfloor
\end{align}
$$
Together with $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}e^{t^2/2}dt \approx 0.658425\;$, we obtain a lower bound for number of zeros.
$$\#\big\{ x \in [0,3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\} - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi}e^{t^2/2} dt > -1.66$$

To obtain an upper bound, we choose a new $\tilde{\eta} = \frac14\log\left(e^{x^2} + \frac{x^2}{4}\right)$. With help of an CAS, one
can verify the corresponding $p_{\tilde{\eta}}(x) \ge p(x)$ for all $x \in [0,3\pi]$. By Sturm-Picone comparison theorem again, we obtain

$$\#\big\{ x \in [0,3\pi] : y_{\tilde{\eta}}(x) = 0\big\}
\ge 
\#\big\{ x \in [0,3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\} - 1
$$
By choosing a suitable $K$, we can make $y_{\tilde{\eta}}$ satisfy

$$
\#\big\{ x \in [0,3\pi] : y_{\tilde{\eta}}(x) = 0\big\}
= \left\lfloor\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} e^{2\tilde{\eta}(t)}dt\right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} \sqrt{e^{t^2} + \frac{t^2}{4}} dt\right\rfloor
$$
Since $\displaystyle\;\sqrt{e^{t^2} + \frac{t^2}{4}} \le  e^{t^2/2} + \frac{t^2}{8}e^{-t^2/2}\;$, this leads to an upper bound for number of zeros.

$$\#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y = 0\big\} -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} e^{t^2/2} dt
\le 
1 + \frac{1}{8\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} t^2 e^{-t^2/2} dt
\approx 1.0498678
$$
Combine these, we obtain an estimate of the number of zeros of $y(x)$ in terms
of an integral.

$$-1.66 < \#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\} -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} e^{t^2/2} dt < 1.05$$

According to WA, the integral evaluates to
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{3\pi} e^{t^2/2} dt \approx
663789642044913452.583222...$$
Since number of zeros is always an integer, we can conclude
$$
663789642044913451
\le
\#\big\{ x \in [\sqrt{2},3\pi] : y(x) = 0\big\}
\le 663789642044913453
$$

Comment: Where do the boundary conditions enter the problem? Can we narrow it down to a single number (rather than a set of 3 numbers) if we choose a boundary condition.

Comment: @Fabian Using a better $\eta$, one can potentially narrow the number down to two. Without any input of boundary condition, two numbers will be as good as one can get. If there is a zero at the boundary, we can get rid of the zero by shifting the corresponding "K" in the true "$\eta$" corresponding to $y(x)$. This means in general, when a zero is lying at the boundary, we can exclude the smallest number from the list.

Comment: @achille hui...thanks for your answer. For me,it will take some serious efforts to understand at its depth. Was my interpretation wrong?

Comment: @mathlover If your "interpretation" means $y(x)$ has at least 3 zeros, then your interpretation is correct. However, since $e^{x^2}$ grows very fast as $x$ increases, using the minimum of $1 = \min\{ e^{x^2} : x \in [0,3\pi]$ as input to Sturm comparsion theorem will significantly underestimate the number of zeros. In this case, it is 17 order of magnitude and it is a little bit too much even for a crude approximation.

Comment: Yes..I agree @achille hui..thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Moved from a [deleted duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148589), answered Feb 18 '17 at 8:44, since it contains a more elementary approach)</sub>

See the [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem) which tells you that you have at least as many roots as $\cos x$ on $[0,3π]$.

You could apply it to the segments $[0,π]$, $[π,2π]$ and $[2π,3π]$ separately to get a better lower bound for the root numbers as you then compare to $y''+e^{(k\pi)^2}y=0$, $k=0,1,2$ so that you get on the respective intervals at least as many roots as $\cos(e^{k^2\pi^2/2}x)$ where the frequencies have numerical values $1,\; 139.045636661,\;
373791533.224$.

With a finer subdivision one can drive this lower bound up to $6.5·10^{17}$ roots inside the interval.

---

Details on the **application of the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem** (*2/21/17*): On $[0,3\pi]$ use $q_1(x)=1$ and $q_2(x)=e^{x^2}$. Then $q_1\le q_2$ and $p_1=1=p_2$, so the theorem applies and any solution $v$ of $v''+q_2v=0$ has at least one root between any two consecutive roots $x_k=k\pi$, $k=0,1,2,3$ of the solution $u(x)=\sin x$ of $u'+q_1u=0$. The roots of $\cos x$ have this property, Which is why one can say that $v$ has at least as many roots as $\cos x$ in that interval.

Comment: ...Getting an opportunity to express my sincere thanks after 3 years. Thanks!