# How to solve a certain linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

I would really appreciate an hint on how to get the exact solution of this linear ODE

\begin{equation}
y'' + e^{x^2}y=0,
\end{equation}

with initial conditions given by $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$.

I already know, from qualitative study and numerical simulations, how the solution behave, but I have no idea on how to get it in closed form.

Comment: You can try to find the power series expansion of $y$ at $x=0$.

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075647/number-of-zeroes-of-solution-to-yxex2yx-0-in-0-3π on approaches to such a solution and its properties.

Comment: If you can find a non-trivial particular solution, the solution is 
\begin{align} y(x)=y_p\left(c_1+c_2\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{y_p^2}\right). 
\end{align}
But of course, finding a particular solution is another story.