# Estimate the number of zeros for the solution for Schrödinger equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have moved heaven and earth to solving the problem for three weeks, but there is no progress...

The problem comes from "Inverse scattering on the line".

Here I want to estimate the number of zeros for the solution for Schrödinger equation $$m''(x,k)+2ikm'(x,k)=q(x)m(x,k),\quad m(x,k)\rightarrow1\ as\ x\rightarrow\infty$$in $Im(k)>0$.

Here $x$ is a real number (it's a 1-dim. Schrodinger equation), and $q(x)$ is a real potential which belongs to $\{q(x):\int^\infty_{-\infty}|q(x)|(1+|t|)dt<\infty\}$

I want to give an explanation for the upper bound of the number of zeros is $\int^{\infty}_x(t-x)|q(t)|dt$.

Previously, I finished that $m(x,k)=1+\sum^\infty_{k=1}g_n(x,k)$, where $$g_n(x,k)=\int^\infty_x\int^{x_n}_x\int^{x_{n-1}}_x...\int^{x_2}_x\prod^{n}_{i=1} q(x_i)\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{e^{2ik(x_i-x_{i-1})}-1}{2ik}dx_1dx_2...dx_n$$ and $x_{-1}$ is $x$.

In this form, when $Im(k)>0$, $m(x,k)$ is analytic.

About $\int^{\infty}_x(t-x)|q(t)|dt$, I have a estimate that
$$|g_n(x,k)|\leq\frac{(\int^{\infty}_x(t-x)|q(t)|dt)^n}{n!}$$
By the way, my advisor told me use Sturm Comparison theorem, so I turn it into $$(e^{2ikx}m'(x,k))'-q(x)e^{2ikx}m(x,k)=0.$$ But I don't have any way to estimate the number of zeros for a differential equation.
Please give me some ideas.

Comment: The function $e^{ikx}m(x,k)$ has the same number of roots and a simplified equation. I'm however not sure how Sturm-Picone works with complex coefficient functions.

Comment: Here is my opinion. I can turn the original 2nd ODE into Strum Liouville system $(e^{2ikx}m')'-q(x)e^{2ikx}m=0$. Then Sturm Comparison theorem can be used. But I don't know which SL system I can make a comparison. About complex coefficient, norm perhaps is enough?

Comment: Another point is, as the solution is complex-valued due to the complex coefficients, there do not need to be any zeros, even if the solution oscillates infinitely around the $x$ axis.

Comment: After two weeks, I have a rough idea that how to solve it and want to share it with you. After we did enough estimate, we had the information that the zeros of the Schrödinger equation only happens when k is a pure imaginary number and the number of k is finite. So Sturm-Picone theorem can be applied in a reasonable sense.

Comment: Or contract to $(e^{ikx}m(x))''=(q(x)-k^2)(e^{ikx}m(x))$. Now you can also apply the WKB approximation to see how the oscillatory behavior develops. See the accepted answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075647/number-of-zeroes-of-solution for how you can use that to get a rather precise root number estimate. My answer there is a more primitive guess that was more than sufficient for the task in question.