# Solve a Second-order linear ordinary differential equation with coefficient $e^{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have troubles solving the following differential equation.

$$y''(x)+e^{x^2}y(x) = 0$$

This is a sample solution family that i plotted:

[image]

How can i deal with the coefficient $e^{x^2}$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075647/number-of-zeroes-of-solution. This WKB like approximation is the best you can do, there is no symbolic solution.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $e^x$ instead of $e^{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will check it out

Comment: Yes, it is $e^{x^2}$

Comment: The differential operator is parity-preserving, so the solution can be divided into an even and odd part. If you write them as $y(x) = f_+(x^2)$ and $y(x) = x f_-(x^2)$, they satisfy the differential equations $4uf_{\pm}'' + (4\mp 2)f_{\pm}' + e^{u}f_{\pm} = 0$. Not sure if that's any easier, though.

Comment: It looks like your family of solutions has only one parameter. I suppose you have some relation between $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ common for all solutions in this family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series solutions, as usual...

$$
y_1 \left( x \right) =1-{\frac{1}{2}}{x}^{2}-{\frac{1}{24}}{x}^{4}+{
\frac{1}{720}}{x}^{6}+{\frac{89}{40320}}{x}^{8}+{\frac{95}{145152}}{x}
^{10}+{\frac{11531}{95800320}}{x}^{12}+{\frac{32899}{2490808320}}{x}^{
14}-{\frac{107909}{597793996800}}{x}^{16}-{\frac{91798843}{
182924963020800}}{x}^{18}+O \left( {x}^{20} \right) 
$$

$$
y_2 \left( x \right) =x-{\frac{1}{6}}{x}^{3}-{\frac{1}{24}}{x}^{5}-{
\frac{1}{144}}{x}^{7}-{\frac{5}{10368}}{x}^{9}+{\frac{149}{1140480}}{x
}^{11}+{\frac{10697}{177914880}}{x}^{13}+{\frac{523759}{37362124800}}{
x}^{15}+{\frac{22811531}{10162497945600}}{x}^{17}+{\frac{772371221}{
3475574297395200}}{x}^{19}+O \left( {x}^{20} \right) 
$$
The general solution is $Ay_1+By_2$.
Of course, these are entire functions, since the DE has no singularities in the complex plane.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! This has helped my understanding.